# How can you duplicate a data frame multiple times into a list

Tags: r

I need help creating a list of identical data frames and automating the process.

I can get the result with the following code:

`df.list <- list(df, df, df)`

However, I would like to accomplish the same thing by inputting the number of repeating data frames I wish to have in the list. So far I have tried:

```
df.list <- list(rep(df, 3))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invert the order of nesting of your calls:

```
rep(list(df), 3L)
```